# TypeScript: convert typeof back to instance

Tags: oop, typescript

I have function that creates instances of given class and I don't how to tell TypeScript that:
function builder returns instances of class passed in first argument

```
class A extends HTMLElement {
  color: 'white'
}

function builder<T extends typeof HTMLElement>(classParam: T) {
  let instance = new classParam()
  return instance
}

let instance = builder(A)
instance.color = 'black'
// Property 'color' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

Is it possible without using type assertion?

Comment: Is changing the signature of builder "allowed" ?

Comment: yes, you can change it

Comment: You can't `new` an HTMLElement though, I don't understand what it is you're trying to do. Are you looking for `document.createElement()` by any chance?

Comment: the code will later use document.createElement I have simplified the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed and explained the problems:

```
class A extends HTMLElement {
  color: string = 'white' // you gave it the type "white", 
                          // but I assume you need the value "white" (and type `string`)
}


function builder<T extends HTMLElement>(classParam: { new(): T }) : T { 
  // previous line:
  // - `typeof` in the generic constraint is not valid
  // - the parameter could not be of type `T`, because you would not be 
  //   able to use `new`. It's now a parameter which has a constructor
  //    which creates a `T`
  // - we are now returning `T`, instead of (implicit) `any`
  let instance = new classParam()
  return instance
}

let instance = builder(A)
instance.color = 'black'
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20extends%20HTMLElement%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20color%20%3A%20string%20%3D%20'white'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20builder%3CT%20extends%20HTMLElement%3E(classParam%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20instance%20%3D%20new%20classParam()%0D%0A%20%20return%20instance%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20instance%20%3D%20builder(A)%0D%0Ainstance.color%20%3D%20'black'%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Property%20'color'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'HTMLElement')

Comment: I got Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T', try it in TypeScript playground

Comment: I assumed your code was valid, but there where some mistakes. Fixed it and tested in the playground